# What is the meaning of this strace message?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, strace

My program is crashing after some time on Ubuntu 18.04 and the last few lines of `strace` are like this:

```
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
6260  write(2, "terminate called after throwing "..., 48) = 48
6260  write(2, "std::system_error", 17) = 17
6260  write(2, "'\n", 2)                = 2
6260  write(2, "  what():  ", 11)       = 11
6260  write(2, "Unknown error -1", 16)  = 16
6260  write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
6260  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
6260  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
6260  getpid()                          = 6260
6260  gettid()                          = 6260
6260  tgkill(6260, 6260, SIGABRT)       = 0
6260  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
6260  --- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=6260, si_uid=1000} ---
6260  +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
```

My understanding of the above message is that `libc.mo` cannot be found. Is my understanding right? If yes, how I can fix it? If not, can someone give me some pointers of how to detect the reason of crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the strace output, you can see that the program is searching for the file `libc.mo`, but that is not the problem here. The `.mo` file contains the translation, and if it not found, messages are usually displayed in English. From the pathnames, your locale seems to be `en_US`, so you shouldn't need a translation.

A hint to the problem is here:

```
6260  write(2, "terminate called after throwing "..., 48) = 48
6260  write(2, "Unknown error -1", 16)  = 16
```

Use a larger size to display the truncated message after "throwing" (`-s 50` or more). It probably contains the exception class name. The other hint is "Unknown error -1", usually not helpful.

If it is not just a program, but your program, run it inside a debugger. You should get a back-trace and much more useful information.